# Data type mismatch error while executing case statement in MS Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure

I am trying to execute a Case statement in an Azure SQL database and receiving a data type mismatch error. Looks like Azure is converting the columns as DOUBLE type by default.

I tried to use the CAST function to cast the data type to string.
Looks like it's not working.

```
   select distinct fsd.load_id, 
    ldd.CARR_SVC_TYPE_CODE,
    ldd.carrier_id,
    ldd.frt_move_catg_code,
    fsd.pymnt_type_code,
    fsd.orig_loc_name AS orig_loc_name,
    fsd.ORIG_LOCATION_ID AS ORIG_LOC_ID,
    fsd.ORIG_CITY_NAME,
    fsd.ORIG_STATE_PROV_CODE, 
    CASE  WHEN fsd.orig_zip_code IS NULL THEN orig.postal_code
    ELSE fsd.ORIG_ZIP_CODE
    END AS O5ZIP,
    CAST (CASE  WHEN fsd.orig_zip_code IS NULL THEN orig.postal_code
    ELSE fsd.ORIG_ZIP_CODE
    END AS CHAR (3)) AS O3ZIP,
    ldd.dest_loc_id,
    ldd.DEST_CITY_NAME,
    ldd.DEST_STATE_PROV_CODE,
    COALESCE(ldd.dest_postal_code, dest.postal_code) AS chk_5dzip,
    CASE  WHEN ldd.dest_postal_code IS NULL THEN dest.postal_code
    ELSE ldd.DEST_POSTAL_CODE
    END AS D5Zip,
    CAST (CASE  WHEN ldd.dest_postal_code IS NULL THEN dest.postal_code
    ELSE ldd.DEST_POSTAL_CODE
    END AS CHAR (3)) AS D3ZIP  ,
   CASE WHEN (CAST(fsd.orig_city_name AS VARCHAR(100)) = CAST(fsd.dest_city_name AS      VARCHAR(100)) | CAST(fsd.orig_state_prov_code AS VARCHAR(100)) =
    CAST(fsd.dest_state_prov_code AS VARCHAR(100))) AND ldf.distance_qty > 100 THEN 15
    ELSE ldf.distance_QTY
    END AS tot_distance_qty ,
    fsd.PO_NBR,
    ldd.LOAD_MABD_DATE,
    ldd.load_ready_date,
    fsd.SHIP_CREATE_DATE,
    ldf.EST_ACCS_COST_AMT,
    ldf.est_stop_chrg_amt,
    ldf.EST_TOTAL_COST_AMT ,
    SUM(fsf.case_qty) / COUNT(fsf.case_qty) AS ShipmentCases,
    SUM(fsf.WEIGHT_QTY) / COUNT(fsf.weight_qty) AS ShipmentWeight,
    SUM(fsf.cube_qty) / COUNT(fsf.cube_qty) AS ShipmentCube 
    FROM
    us_trans_dm_vm.load_fact ldf
    INNER JOIN us_trans_dm_vm.load_dim ldd ON ldd.load_sk_id = ldf.load_sk_id
    INNER JOIN us_trans_dm_vm.freight_shipment_dim fsd ON fsd.load_id = ldd.load_id
    INNER JOIN us_trans_dm_vm.freight_shipment_fact fsf ON fsf.shipment_sk_id = fsd.shipment_sk_id
    INNER JOIN us_wc_vm.purchase_order p ON p.po_nbr = fsd.po_nbr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ww_core_dim_vm.dc_cur orig ON fsd.orig_location_id = orig.dc_nbr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ww_core_dim_vm.dc_cur dest ON ldd.dest_loc_id = dest.dc_nbr 

    WHERE


    fsd.ship_create_date BETWEEN p.order_date AND date_add(p.order_date,5) AND
    ldd.LOAD_READY_DATE >= date_add(current_date(),-5)  AND 

    ldd.CURR_LOAD_STATUS_CODE NOT IN ('CANCEL') AND
    ldd.current_ind = 'Y' AND
    fsd.current_ind = 'Y' AND
    ldd.dest_loc_id IN (6908,6909,7100,7101,4792,4889,6274,6289,6299,6492,6493,6494,6495,6496,6499,6596,6597,6598,6697,6698,6699,8206,8229,8230,8231,8232,8234,8235,4892,4894,4895,4896,8307) AND
    fsf.carrier_sk_id > 0 AND ldd.frt_move_catg_code NOT IN ('PPD') AND

    p.col_ppd NOT IN ('P') AND
    (orig.country_code = 'US' OR orig.country_code IS NULL) AND
    (dest.country_code = 'US' OR dest.country_code IS NULL) 

    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25
```

Above is the complete code snippet.

Below is the 2 versions of CASE statements :

**1st version:**

```
CASE WHEN fsd.orig_city_name | fsd.orig_state_prov_code = fsd.dest_city_name |    fsd.dest_state_prov_code AND ldf.distance_qty > 100 THEN 15                                                                                                 ELSE ldf.distance_QTY  END AS tot_distance_qty
```

**2nd version:**

```
 CASE WHEN (CAST(fsd.orig_city_name AS VARCHAR(100))  = CAST(fsd.dest_city_name AS  VARCHAR(100)) | CAST(fsd.orig_state_prov_code AS VARCHAR(100)) =
    CAST(fsd.dest_state_prov_code AS VARCHAR(100))) AND ldf.distance_qty > 100 THEN 15
    ELSE ldf.distance_QTY
    END AS tot_distance_qty
```

Both aren't working for me.

*Copy pasting the entire error message:*

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve
>   '(CAST(CAST(fsd.`dest_city_name` AS STRING) AS DOUBLE) |
>   CAST(CAST(fsd.`orig_state_prov_code` AS STRING) AS DOUBLE))' due to
>   data type mismatch: '(CAST(CAST(fsd.`dest_city_name` AS STRING) AS
>   DOUBLE) | CAST(CAST(fsd.`orig_state_prov_code` AS STRING) AS DOUBLE))'
>   requires integral type, not double;

Comment: The error seems really clear.  Sample data, desired results, and a simplified query would help convey your question.

Comment: Hi -I am able to resolve this error. @Admin can you please delete this post? I am unable to delete it myself :(

Comment: Hi @KrutikaDesai, you don't need to delete this post, you can post and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members.